# Use reflection to get fields of Generic Class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, predicate

I would like to get the fields of Generic class "T" using reflection in order to build a basic Filter Predicate from all the Type=String fields.

Using T.getFields doesn't seem to be an option which is what I assumed I would use.

This class is to be used in a JTextField which I intend to use to search over various objects. I will pass it additional search criteria, but for basic functionality I want to default to searching all String fields.

```
public class SearchListener<T,C extends Collection<T>> implements DocumentListener {

private JList jlist;
private C staticCollection;
private List<Predicate<T>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
 //get the String fields, and build Predicate from them.. add to predicateList.



public SearchListener(JList jlist, List<Predicate<T>> predicateList, C collection) {        
    this.jlist = jlist;
    this.staticCollection=collection;
    this.predicateList=predicateList;
}

@Override
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

@Override
public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

@Override
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
    filter();
}

private void filter() {
    jlist.setModel((ListModel)staticCollection);
    C items = (C) jlist.getModel();

    Stream<T> itemStream = items.stream().filter(x ->{
        Stream<Predicate<T>> predicateStream= predicateList.stream();
        return predicateStream.map(predicate -> predicate.test(x)).reduce((a,b)->a && b).get();
    });
    ArrayList<T> collect = itemStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
    C name = (C)collect;
    jlist.setModel((ListModel)name);
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to reflect the fields of a class then you need the corresponding `Class` object.  You cannot get that from a type parameter.  If you want it, you need to ensure that the `Class` or possibly an instance of it is provided to your code as a constructor or method argument.

Comment: There are almost certainly better ways to do this than using reflection.  I think a `Collection<Function<T, ?>>` representing each of the bean properties of `T` would be the most reliable, assuming you’re in control of what gets passed as `T`.  If you aren’t, you can determine the bean properties yourself with a [beans Introspector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html).